# Operation is not supported for read-only collection

Tags: android-studio

Operation is not supported for read-only collection in android studio after updating to android hedgehog.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTswO.jpg)

Reinstall the android studio.
Also try the older version of android studio.
Also update my windows.